# How to deal with the props and tightly coupled components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a couple components which are tightly coupled to each other. The highest component receives prop called `options`. The prop `options` is passed down through next components and so on.

Which is the best way to emit changes from nested components to each others? I wouldn't rather use redux in this case.

Comment: You can use `context` of React or Redux. What's the problem?

Comment: How context could solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

This example will work for **React16.3 and above**.

[Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react16-context?file=index.js) to check working example.

## a) Get Data from parent component to nested chid conponent using context api of react

**1. Grand Parent Component**

> Context lets us pass a value deep into the component tree  without
>   explicitly threading it through every component.  Create a context for
>   the current theme (with "light" as the default).

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Use a Provider to pass the current theme to the tree below.
    // Any component can read it, no matter how deep it is.
    // In this example, we're passing "dark" as the current value.
    const theme = "dark";
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
        <Toolbar />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**2. Parent Component**

> A component in the middle doesn't have to pass the theme down
>   explicitly anymore.

```
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**3. Child Component**

```
function ThemedButton(props) {
  // Use a Consumer to read the current theme context.
  // React will find the closest theme Provider above and use its value.
  // In this example, the current theme is "dark".
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => <div>{theme}</div>}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Replace **theme** to **options** in your case.

For more detail take the reference of react doc. [Click here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

## b) Store data from parent component to store and get it in nested child component using redux

> Here you are getting data from state and passing options data to
>   your component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  options: state.options,
});
```

> Here you are connecting your component from state

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: @siwymilek:- This will solve your problem if you are using react 16.3. It will work differently in below version. Which version you are using.

Comment: Not quite – it works only one way, passing props down. Anyhow, I decided to use redux with context. In my highest component I subscribe store and override context value.

Comment: @siwymilek First of all if you are using redux then no need to use context api of react. one way to use content in which you are passing props from top most component and you can get it in child component or nested child component. Other one is using redux, In that you can dispatch action and store data, after that you can use 'connect' method from react-redux to get store data.

Comment: I used context api consciously – this is way better solution than passing props thorugh many components... and there is no reason to connect all components

Comment: @siwymilek As you said, you override context value, now I have added code for redux to get data from store using connect method of react-redux to get options data

Comment: @siwymilek:- It totally depend on you and your use case. You can choose whatever you what. I'm using both method in my application.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right – but I would rather take my solution, anyway thank you for help :)